# Integrals on a positive interval yielding smaller values.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f:[0, \infty) \rightarrow \Bbb R $ is integrable  on every interval $[0,b]$ for $b > 0$. Show that if $\int_0^{\infty} f$ converges then for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists an $M$ such that $ M \leq a \ < b$ and 
$| {\int_a^b f }| < \epsilon$

Thoughts: I am thinking this is essentially saying that as $a$ approaches infinity that the function's integral from $a$ to $b$ has to get smaller and smaller otherwise it would not converge but I am not sure how to make this rigorous. Any hints much appreciated.

Comment: For any $e>0$ there exists $M$ such that $|\int_a^bf(x)dx|<e$ whenever $M<a<b.$ ...  For a classical or Riemann integral, $\int_0^{\infty}f(x)dx$ is defined as $\lim _{a\to \infty}\int_0^af(x)dx, $ provided that this limit exists. So you can just use the usual basic results about  $\lim_{a\to \infty}g(a).$

Comment: @user254665 what is g(a).

Comment: In this case $g(a)=\int_0^a f(x)dx.$